# Loopback Model - add a count field for a hasMany relation Model

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

Is there a way to count the number of instance of a related model, without using an `include` on the filter?

I already found [loopback-counts-mixin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loopback-counts-mixin), but I am hoping that there is a native way of doing it.

Comment: There's not, there are few potential options, you could use fields filter for introducing new $count field, but it does not offer such a possibility https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Fields-filter.html, you could use include, but it also does not exist https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Include-filter.html, there's also chapter on querying related models but it also does not include aggregate functions https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Querying-related-models.html, so... no native way so far